# Toggle Button Checked Property Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, togglebutton

I add a toggle button on Windows Phone 8 . When i checked (on), its save a value in Isolated storage and I check that value in constructor whatever it has a toggle value or null. If there is a toggle  value I want to display toggle button checked . But  I dont know the property to  how to checked it  when application is run .

Toggle Button XAML :

```
<toolkit:ToggleSwitch x:Name="toggle" Content="On" Width="165" FontSize="28"   VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
```

C# :

```
 public Subscription()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.toggle.Checked += new EventHandler<RoutedEventArgs>(toggle_Checked);
        this.toggle.Unchecked += new EventHandler<RoutedEventArgs>(toggle_Unchecked);

        var appSettings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;


        if (HasSValue() == "NoValue")
        {
            // Here i want to Display  toggle button unchecked
        }
        else
        {
            // Here i want to Display toggle button checked

        }
    }

    void toggle_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.toggle.Content = "Off";
        this.toggle.SwitchForeground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);

        var appSettings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
        appSettings.Remove("toggleValue");
        appSettings.Save();

    }

    void toggle_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.toggle.Content = "On";
        this.toggle.SwitchForeground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
        MessageBox.Show("R U Sure ?");
        var appSettings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
        appSettings.Add("toggleValue", "MAHIN");
        appSettings.Save();
    }

    public string HasSValue()
    {
        var appSettings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
        if (appSettings.Contains("toggleValue"))
        {
            return (string) appSettings["toggleValue"];
        }
        else
        {
            return "NoValue";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
    if (HasSValue() == "NoValue")
    {
        this.toggle.IsChecked = false;
    }
    else
    {
        this.toggle.IsChecked = true;

    }
```

Hope this helps

**Update your Constructor as follows**

```
public Subscription()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var appSettings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;


    if (HasSValue() == "NoValue")
    {
        // Here i want to Display  toggle button unchecked
    }
    else
    {
        // Here i want to Display toggle button checked

    }

    this.toggle.Checked += new EventHandler<RoutedEventArgs>(toggle_Checked);
    this.toggle.Unchecked += new EventHandler<RoutedEventArgs>(toggle_Unchecked);
}
```

Comment: Its working but problem is that when I checked  this toggle and  revisit this page form another page, the toggle_Checked() is call again coz I check toggle state in constructor. So how can i rid from it ?

Comment: Update your constructor as per my edit of this answer

Comment: Thnx bro , Its working fine . Can u plz explain this two line

this.toggle.Checked += new EventHandler<RoutedEventArgs>(toggle_Checked);
    this.toggle.Unchecked += new EventHandler<RoutedEventArgs>(toggle_Unchecked);

Comment: Both these lines are checked and unchecked handlers of toggle button. in your previous code they were handled at the start of the constructor. I moved these lines at after toggle check/uncecked is set. now the events are registered after we have set the value to toggle button is set.